# cvs: write tag information into file

Tags: tags, cvs

When we make a new release for our customer we tag our project in eclipse (cvs) with a release number. (e.g. 2.11.0)

Is it possible to write this tag (2.11.0) into a file, so that our customer can tell us which version he has installed currently?

Cheers,
Laci

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`$Name$` keyword](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_12.html#SEC100). This will expand to the tag name if you checkout a particular tag. eg.

```
$Name: v2_11_0 $
```

As an aside, 2.11.0 would not be a valid cvs tag because it starts with a number and contains restricted characters:

```
[burhan@orion cvstest]$ cvs tag 2.11.0
cvs [tag aborted]: tag `2.11.0' must start with a letter
[burhan@orion cvstest]$ cvs tag v2.11.0
cvs [tag aborted]: tag `v2.11.0' must not contain the characters `$,.:;@/'
```